# Multithreaded file processing and reporting

Tags: java, multithreading, file, callable

I have an application that processes data stored in a number of files from an input directory and then produces some output depending on that data.

So far, the application works in a sequential basis, i.e. it launches a "manager" thread that

- Reads the contents of the input directory into a `File[]` array
- Processes each file in sequence and stores results
- Terminates when all files are processed

I would like to convert this into a multithreaded application, in which the "manager" thread

- Reads the contents of the input directory into a `File[]` array
- Launches a number of "processor" threads, each of which processes a single file, stores results and returns a summary report for that file to the "manager" thread
- Terminates when all files have been processed

The number of "processor" threads would be at most equal to the number of files, since they would be recycled via a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Any solution avoiding the use of `join()` or `wait()/notify()` would be preferrable.

Based on the above scenario:

1. What would be the best way of having those "processor" threads reporting back to the "manager" thread? Would an implementation based on [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) and [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) make sense here?
2. How can the "manager" thread know when all "processor" threads are done, i.e. when all files have been processed?
3. Is there a way of "timing" a processor thread and terminating it if it takes "too long" (i.e., it hasn't returned a result despite the lapse of a pre-configured amount of time)?

Any pointers to, or examples of, (pseudo-)source code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Am no threading expert but here's my quick shot to give you a direction:

1.  You can use the wait/notify mechanism to control the reporting behavior.
2.  The main manager thread can process data as and when files are read.  Does it need to wait till all files are processed?
3.  There is TimerTask that can come handy in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The manager thread does not need to wait for all processor threads to finish, but it does need to know when they did. I would rather not use wait()/notify(), hence the reference to the Callable interface. In any case, please put your comments in an answer so that I can vote for it. :-)

Comment: Will you be needing to synch access to a common resource? Like a file or cache you're gathering your results in?

Comment: Yes, there will be a common "sink" for the results of each individual processor thread, but that will take care of synchronization itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do this without using `join()` or `wait()`/`notify()` yourself.

You should take a look at [java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) to start with.

The way I see it you should write the following classes:

- `FileSummary` - Simple value object that holds the result of processing a single file
- `FileProcessor implements Callable<FileSummary>` - The strategy for converting a file into a FileSummary result
- `File Manager` - The high level manager that creates FileProcessor instances, submits them to a work queue and then aggregates the results.

The FileManager would then look something like this:

```
class FileManager {
   private CompletionService<FileSummary> cs; // Initialize this in constructor

   public FinalResult processDir(File dir) {
      int fileCount = 0;
      for(File f : dir.listFiles()) {
         cs.submit(new FileProcessor(f));
         fileCount++;
      }

      for(int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
         FileSummary summary = cs.take().get();
         // aggregate summary into final result;
      }
   }
```

If you want to implement a timeout you can use the `poll()` method on CompletionService instead of `take()`.

Comment: This is really close to what I was thinking with respect to using Callable/Future objects. The ExecutorCompletionService is a cool suggestion! An alternative to poll() could be using a get() with a timeout. Please edit the get() call, it should be cs.take().get(), not cs.take.get(). Thanks! :-)

Comment: @PNS actually I'm not sure using a timeout on get() would work because take() will block until there is a result available, i.e. get() will never block.

Comment: Correct if using the ExecutorCompletionService, but if not, the timeout can be used.

Answer (score 1):

`wait()/notify()` are very low level primitives and you are right in wanting to avoid them.

The simplest solution would be to use a thread-safe queues (or stacks, etc. -- it doesn't really matter in this case). Before starting the worker threads, your main thread can add all the `File`s to the thread-safe queue/stack. Then start the worker threads, and let them all pull `File`s and process them until there are none left.

The worker threads can add results to another thread-safe queue/stack, where the main thread can get them from. The main thread knows how many `File`s there were, so when it has retrieved the same number of results, it will know that the job is finished.

Something like a `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue` would work, and there are other thread-safe collections in `java.util.concurrent` which would also be fine.

You also asked about terminating worker threads which are taking too long. I will tell right up front: if you can make the code which runs on the worker threads robust enough that you can safely leave this feature out, you will make things a lot simpler.

If you do need this feature, the simplest and most reliable solution is to have a per-thread "terminate" flag, and make the worker task code check that flag frequently and exit if it is set. Make a custom class for workers, and include a `volatile boolean` field for this purpose. Also include a setter method (because of `volatile`, it doesn't need to be `synchronized`).

If a worker discovers that its "terminate" flag is set, it could push its `File` object *back on the work queue/stack* so another thread can process it. Of course, if there is some problem which means the `File` *cannot* be successfully processed, this will lead to an infinite cycle.

The best is to make the worker code very simple and robust, so you don't need to worry about it "not terminating".

Answer (score 1):

1. No need for them to report back. Just have a count of the number of jobs remaining to be done and have the thread decrement that count when it's done.
2. When the count reaches zero of jobs remaining to be done, all the "processor" threads are done.
3. Sure, just add that code to the thread. When it starts working, check the time and compute the stop time. Periodically (say when you go to read more from the file), check to see if it's past the stop time and, if so, stop.